# How can I see history of the "at" command in AIX?

Tags: ksh, aix, at

I'm experiencing a strange problem where occasionally the `at` command appears to not be running the command I've configured it to run.

For example:

```
at -t 201510071042
runsomescript
<Ctrl-D>
```

`runsomescript` does not run at 2015/10/07 10:42am, for some reason.  Where can I see *why* `at` failed to run the command?  I'm looking for some kind of log file for the `at` process.

Also, I am aware `at` sends mail. Having said that, I'm not getting an email either when `at` fails to execute the command.

If I run `at -lov` immediately after submitting the job, I see it in the queue to be ran at the appropriate time.

---

Additional info as of 2016-02-17

When the `at` command fails, mail contains the following "Cron Job Failure" message:

```
Cron: 0481-072 Cannot change to your home directory.
```

Comment: If you can re-test, check the return code from at ($?) as well as the output of `at -l` (lower-case ELL) to see if your job made it to the queue. I assume that the contents of at.allow and at.deny are not changing in the interim?

Comment: I suppose I should have added that `at -lov` does show the job is in the queue, set for the appropriate time.  I have no idea what is in `at.allow` or `at.deny`; presumably those are global settings?  i.e. I'd need root to see them?

Comment: the at.* files are in /var/adm/cron, which may require root privileges to see. If your jobs are being submitted, though, you're beyond that point. Next thing I wonder about is the shell that it's being run as -- bsh, csh, or ksh.

Comment: KornShell is the shell.

Comment: Can you view the /var/adm/cron/log file to see if your at job spec (userid.NNNN.a) shows as being run? Just curious how far it's making it.

Comment: I don't have root, and so I get access denied trying to cd into /var/adm/cron - I'll see if I can get someone with root to look.  Thanks!

Comment: Just curious if you found an answer to this?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - I have not been able to see `at` results in `/var/adm/cron/log`, and no, I haven't yet found an answer.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Curious that cron appears to accept the job but doesn't run it. If you can reproduce it, a PMR may be in order.

Comment: a PMR ?  What is that?

Comment: Problem Management Record (ticket / service request) with IBM - to request help with their software.

Comment: Is there a reason your home directory is not accessible at that time? NFS issues?

Answer (score 1):

[man at](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/at.htm?cp=ssw_aix_53%2F1-2-0-0-46)

> The at command mails you all output from standard output and standard error for the scheduled commands, unless you redirect that output.

So make sure you can send mail using `sendmail`, and make sure your script doesn't redirect errors (e.g. to `/dev/null`).

Comment: thanks, I should have mentioned in my question that I am aware `at` sends mail.  Having said that, I'm not getting an email either when `at` fails to execute the command.

Comment: As the user that this at job ran under, did you check his local mailfile via `mail` command ?

Comment: yes, `mail` typically has output from the `at` command; however not in these particular instances.

Comment: I've added an error message into my question that I was able to see (finally) in mail.